# How to transfer amount from paypal account to paypal account?

Tags: node.js, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

The below code is a normal transaction from a user to the merchant account. My requirement is to reward customers for correct answering in a way that the application will have some amount in PayPal balance and it will be transferred as rewards to the customers PayPal account which is not a customer marchent relation.  Is there any similar code snippet that can be used for PayPal to papal money transferring?

```
gateway.transaction.sale({ amount: "1000.00",paymentMethodNonce:nonceFromTheClient,options: {submitForSettlement: true },deviceData: req.body.device_data}, function() {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution
1.create a developer account
2.Create sandbox accounts. one for facilitator and one for customer from developer dashboard.
3.Create APP and get APP and get client id and secret key.
4.npm install paypal-rest-sdk(https://www.npmjs.com/package/paypal-rest-sdk)
5.https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/payout/create_single_payout.js